# ITC AVANT GARDE Slanted A V & Unique N T & H -

Tags: fonts

I am not a designer just a person trying to find the right font for a presentation. I love the examples of [ITC Avant Garde Gothic Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/avant-garde-gothic)  but when I look at the actual letters in all the various versions I don't see the extreme slanted A,V or the N that & H that bend inward. Is that a designer customization? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are in what is called the Glyphs or open type features of the font, extended characters that you can't always access from all programs.  They also appear to be in the later versions of the font, my old versions don't have them.

Not knowing what programs you are using, I can't give you instructions on how to access them, but I was able to recreate the look with ITC Avant Garde Pro Medium that I have.

[image: Text example]

If you search for your program and add insert glyphs or access open type features, you should be able to find instructions on how to do that.  Of course, you will have to have purchased and installed the correct version of the font also.

You can see all the glyphs available for all the different versions of Avant Garde by [clicking on the "glyphs" tab](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/avant-garde-gothic?tab=glyphs) on the MyFonts website.

Comment: OMG This is soooo helpful! Thanks a million!!!

Comment: @MorganLawley You are very welcome! good luck!  If you are having problems with how to insert, edit your question with what program(s) you are using and I will add instructions to my answer for that specific program.